# Cannot connect to local PHP site (Undefined index and Undefined variable error)

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

When I try to connect php site locally I find have error using xampp:

```
Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\xampp\htdocs\logoring.au\template.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined variable: body in C:\xampp\htdocs\logoring.au\template.php on line 42

Warning: include(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\logoring.au\template.php on line 42

Warning: include(): Failed opening '' for inclusion (includ
e_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\logoring.au\template.php on line 42
```

But every thing is working online (at www.logoring.com.au).

Comment: Please show us your code! And say where which line is!

Comment: Your online doesn't have error_reporting for warnings on..

Answer (score 1):

You are using a variable in line 42 that doesn't exist (maybe due to a typo in the variable name).

This leads to a warning being shown in PHP, but execution continues with a `NULL` value. Next `include` complains about this empty value being passed in as a file name.

That's all I can tell without seeing the actual `template.php` code ...

Comment: This is the exact error, OP needs to set said variables otherwise errors will occur.